# Ban IP, IP range, DNS or Agend with PHP (Laravel) and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to implement a ban system. Firstly, I will create a filter that will make sure banned users are redirected to a page informing them about the ban.
I use Laravel and MySQL as database. My table could look like this:

```
id, ip , range, dns, agent, reason, endofban
```

or like this

```
id, rule, reason, endofban
```

where `reason` could be a JSON string like this:

```
{ "ip": "123.22.12.*" }
{ "dns": "malicious.dns.com" }
{ "range": "123.22.12.0 - 123.22.14.0" }
```

The advantage of the last one is being more compact but I don't know if there's a fast way to check that JSON against the information of the visitor. I don't want to get all of it from the database then do a `for` loop to make sure no rule returns positive. I want to make the check in the database. This must be done every-time a page is loaded, so it must be fast. What do you think? Any other solution?
Also, how would I check an IP range or wildcard in MySQL?

Comment: Then simply query `WHERE reason LIKE '%?%'` and pass in the ip as the parameter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ip` is redundant with `range`.  A single IP is simply a range where the start and end are the same value.

I would create two values, `ip_range_start` and `ip_range_end`.  Instead of storing strings, store the IP address as an integer (i.e., the result of [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)).  Then, when you run your query you can say:

```
SELECT *
FROM AccessDenyList
WHERE INET_ATON('192.0.2.115') BETWEEN ip_start_range AND ip_end_range
```

Comment: I think this is the best idea but wouldn't it be faster if I convert the visitor's ip to its long value, store everything as long in the database and compare them just as numbers? In this case you just convert IP to long once, with PHP. INET_ATON would make the conversion for each row, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Ali That's what i'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

Normalise your datastructure. The JSON is part of your (relational?) data, so save an IP as an IP, a range as a range, and query against that.

So make datatypes you can check against (in your database). This does mean you have to check with an OR for all these types (ip = xxxx OR dns = yyy or ip-inragne(zzz), but that's a given :)